# Unknown Interaction Error in JS Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I make a bot about Valorant. I can deploy commands, I can run bot, but when I use command that error appear. These are my code. Pls help me, I dont know where I were wrong and how to fix.[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwxuu.png) [deploy_command.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCDPc.png) [commands/shop.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew6c0.png) [Error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG6YY.png)

I dont know how to fix, sometime it run sometime error appears. ;-;

Comment: please paste your whole code, screenshots are not helpful here.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that is first time I ask in stackoverflow, sorry. ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the following code:

```js
// insert between line 14 and 15 of shop.js
await interaction.deferReply();

// replace line 32 of shop.js with:
return interaction.followUp(
```

This will allow you to have an extra wait time between the moment you **receive** the interaction and the moment you need to reply it.

Comment: Thank you, that is 1st time I ask in sof, sorry because of using screenshot. ;-;

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as valid if it helped you

Comment: I have other question, I used that command and time between the moment receiving the interaction and the moment replying is so long. How can I decrease it?